# IoT Raspberry Pi Sensor Tag

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, iot

I am trying build a IoT small application, using IBM Bluemix platform. I found a video of Ryan J Baxter's on connecting a Sensor Tag to the IoT Cloud Foundation with a Beagle-bone. Now I'm trying the same procedure with a Raspberry Pi device instead of a Beagle-Bone, facing some issues with the `sensor-tag.js` file we are not able to get the cfg parameter values like `cfg type`, `cfg org`, `cfg id` from `config.properties` file.

I got the mac address which I gave when I'm registering the device I gave my Raspberry Pi mac address as it is connected to my Ethernet `eth0`.

```
    if(cfg.id != deviceId) {
        console.warn('The device MAC address does not match the ID in the configuration file.');
    }
    //------------- This is where I'm facing  a problem --------

    var clientId = ['d', cfg.org, cfg.type, cfg.id].join(':');

    var client = mqtt.connect("mqtts://" + cfg.org + 
      '.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883', 
      {
        "clientId" : clientId,
        "keepalive" : 30,
        "username" : "use-token-auth",
        "password" : cfg['auth-token']
      });
    client.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('MQTT client connected to IBM IoT Cloud.');
    });
    client.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('client error' + err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
    client.on('close', function() {
      console.log('client closed');
      process.exit(1);
    });
    monitorSensorTag(client);
  });
});

function monitorSensorTag(client) {
  console.log('Make sure the Sensor Tag is on!');
```

Comment: Please make sure that the bracket match in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using raspberry pi, take a look at the recipe for raspberry pi https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/raspberry-pi/

There is also source code for raspberry pi on GitHub which may be helpful: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-raspberrypi/

Using the recipe, you store the device info in a device.cfg file and it is used by the IoT service when you connect.
/etc/iotsample-raspberrypi/device.cfg

EDITED TO ADD: Looking at the logs, I see you registered the Raspberry Pi Device with a different ID than what you are using.  Please register the device with the correct ID that I emailed to you.

Comment: yes. it is already done before but I want my sensor tag to be connected to the IoT Cloud using Raspberry Pi. If I have to do this I have to connect my raspberry pi in a register mode is it??

Comment: Did you register the raspberry pi to the IoT Foundation?   It expects the mac address to be in lowercase with no colons.

Comment: If you let me know your org, I will check the IoT logs to see if I can find your connection errors.

Comment: I registered my raspberry pi to the IoT Foundation mac address is perfect. But it is not connected to the IoT Cloud and not publishing any data.

Comment: I see this error 2015-07-15T12:21:16  Token auth failed (Device does not exist): ClientID='d:rpwtjr:Raspberrypi:                                                          Your org shows  registered devices both "pi" and "Raspberrypi"   with the same ID.  Did you only recently add the Raspberrypi name?

Comment: Exactly you are right, I already registered the device in the name of "pi" or "RaspberryPi" with a trail Bluemix account. I  think the Trail version is completed, now I'm trying the same procedure with same Raspberry pi with another bluemix trail account. can i do this or not????

Comment: You should be able to do it with a new trial account, but you'll have to register the Pi under the new account because when you create a new IOT service under new account it will have a different org.